# Error on PHPhotoLibrary, cannot save video

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, phphotolibrary

I am trying to save a video in my photo library. But sometimes I get an error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (PHPhotosErrorDomain error -1.)

This is my code:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: exporter!.outputURL!)
               }) { saved, error in
                   if saved {
                       print("video saved to camera roll")
                   } else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                }
               }
```

Comment: Did you get any solution. I am also facing the same error.

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve this by removing the AVVideoQualityKey within AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey in my video output settings for AVAssetWriter.